# Delete from double Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to delete a node from a doubly linked list but I have a problem
and this problem is when the node is the first or in the middle it prints 0 instead and it's not really deleted , but it works well when it's the last node in the list and here is the code:

```
dList* del(dList*ptr, int x)
{

    dList *itr = NULL;
    for( itr = ptr; itr != NULL; itr = itr -> next)
    {
            // if the element is the first in the list
            if(itr -> value == x && itr -> prev == NULL)
            {
                itr -> next -> prev = NULL;
                ptr = itr -> next;
                free(itr);
            }
            // if the element is the last in the list
            else if(itr -> value == x && itr -> next == NULL)
            {
                itr -> prev -> next = NULL;

                free(itr);
            }
            // if its in the middle

            else if(itr -> value == x){
                    (itr -> prev) -> next = itr -> next;
                    (itr -> next) -> prev = itr -> prev;
                    free(itr);
            }
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: yes i mean that , i will edit it atm

Comment: i will try to handle that thanks  alot !

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
for( itr = ptr; itr != NULL; itr = itr -> next)
{
        // if the element is the first in the list
        if(itr -> value == x && itr -> prev == NULL)
        {
            itr -> next -> prev = NULL;
            ptr = itr -> next;
            free(itr);
        }
        // ...
```

has undefined behavior.

For example in the third expression of the for loop

```
itr = itr -> next
```

you are using already deleted pointer

```
free(itr);
```

If the list for example has only one node then `itr->next` is equal to `NULL`. So again this statement

```
itr -> next -> prev = NULL;
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

The function can look much simpler if to pass the head node by reference through  pointer to it.

Also a more useful return value is the number of the deleted nodes in the list.

The function definition can look the following way

```
size_t del( dList **ptr, int value )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *ptr != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *ptr )->value == value )
        {
            dList *tmp = *ptr;
            *ptr = ( *ptr )->next;
            if ( *ptr ) ( *ptr )->prev = tmp->prev;

            free( tmp );
            ++n;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = &( *ptr )->next;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dList
{
    int value;
    struct dList *prev;
    struct dList *next;
} dList;


size_t del( dList **ptr, int value )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( *ptr != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *ptr )->value == value )
        {
            dList *tmp = *ptr;
            *ptr = ( *ptr )->next;
            if ( *ptr ) ( *ptr )->prev = tmp->prev;

            free( tmp );
            ++n;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = &( *ptr )->next;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int push_front( dList **head, int value )
{
    dList *new_node = malloc( sizeof( dList ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->prev = NULL;
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next = *head;

        if ( *head ) ( *head )->prev = new_node;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void out( dList *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d --> ", head->value );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    dList *head = NULL;

    push_front( &head, 1 );
    push_front( &head, 2 );
    push_front( &head, 1 );

    out( head );

    size_t n = del( &head, 1 );

    printf( "%zu nodes are deleted.\n", n );
    out( head );

    n = del( &head, 2 );

    printf( "%zu nodes are deleted.\n", n );
    out( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 --> 2 --> 1 --> NULL
2 nodes are deleted.
2 --> NULL
1 nodes are deleted.
NULL
```

Comment: I think you mean ptr = itr -> next?  if the address of itr -> next is 300 for example and i moved the ptr "head" pointing to it , and the address of itr itself is 200 so i do not need itr anymore?

Comment: I'v jeust realized that the very same moment. Sorry